# Async redux actions tests always return pending

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, axios, jest-mock-axios

I am writing tests for some async actions however the tests are failing because the `type` which is returned is always `REQUEST_PENDING`. So even for the tests when the data is fetched the type does not change and the test fails. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

So the `REQUEST_SUCCESS` and `REQUEST_FAILED` are the tests that are always returning `REQUEST_PENDING`

This is my `actions.js`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  REQUEST_PENDING,
  REQUEST_SUCCESS,
  REQUEST_FAILED,
} from './constants';

export const setSearchField = (payload) => ({ type: SEARCH_EVENT, payload });

export const requestRobots = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_PENDING,
    });
    try {
      const result = await axios.get('//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
      dispatch({ type: REQUEST_SUCCESS, payload: result.data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({ type: REQUEST_FAILED, payload: error });
    }
  };
};
```

and this is my `actions.test.js`

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import {
  REQUEST_PENDING,
  REQUEST_SUCCESS,
  REQUEST_FAILED,
} from './constants';
import * as actions from './actions';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]);
const payload = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'robocop',
    email: 'robocop@gmail.com',
    key: 1,
  },
];


describe('handles requestRobots', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Runs before each test in the suite
    store.clearActions();
  });

  const store = mockStore();
  store.dispatch(actions.requestRobots());
  const action = store.getActions();

  it('Should return REQUEST_PENDING action', () => {
    expect(action[0]).toEqual({
      type: REQUEST_PENDING,
    });
  });


  it('Should return REQUEST_SUCCESS action', () => {
    mock.onGet('//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').reply(200, {
      data: payload,
    });


    return store.dispatch(actions.requestRobots()).then(() => {
      const expectedActions = [
        {
          type: REQUEST_SUCCESS,
          payload: {
            data: payload,
          },
        },
      ];
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });

  it('Should return REQUEST_FAILURE action', () => {
    mock.onGet('//jsonplaceholder.typicod.com/users').reply(400, {
      data: payload,
    });


    return store.dispatch(actions.requestRobots()).then(() => {
      const expectedActions = [
        {
          type: REQUEST_FAILED,
          payload: {
            data: ['Error: Request failed with status code 404'],
          },
        },
      ];
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle of a thunk action is that it will dispatch the `REQUEST_PENDING` action at the start of every call and then dispatch a `REQUEST_FAILED` or `REQUEST_SUCCESS` action at the end.

In your second and third test cases, the `store.getActions()` array actually has two elements: the pending action and the results action.  You need to `expect` that the actions is an array with both.  The `REQUEST_FAILED` and `REQUEST_SUCCESS` actions are there, but you aren't seeing them because they are the second element.

Define your `pendingAction` as a variable since you'll need it in all three tests.

```
const pendingAction = {
  type: REQUEST_PENDING
}
```

Then include it in your `expectedActions` array.

```
const expectedActions = [
  pendingAction,
    {
      type: REQUEST_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        data: payload
      }
    }
]
```

This will cause your success test to pass.  I did a quick run of the tests and the failure test still fails because it is not properly mocking the API failure.  Right now it is returning a success because the `requestRobots` function uses the real axios object and not the mock axios adapter.  But maybe something in your environment handles this differently.

Comment: I just had to include `afterEach(() => {
    mock.reset();
  });` This fixed the test for failure